# Rod sliding on a frictionless surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

> A uniform rod$(m,l)$ is standing vertically on a horizontal frictionless surface. Gravity is downwards and uniform. I give its upper end a little push and off it goes. I want to find the Normal Force(and all other variables) as a function of time.

Here's what I do :

$mg-N=ma$

Where a is downward acceleration(and the only) of centre of mass wrt ground.

Next, I think of conservation of energy. I assume it rotates $\theta$ from vertical

$mg\frac{l}{2}(1-\cos\theta)=K.E.$

I have problem writing expression of its Kinetic Energy. I have studied about instantaneous centre of rotation.

So, I can write its speed and rotational kinetic energy about it as $K.E.$? Also How do I find relation between $\omega$ (angular velocity about that instantaneous centre) and velocity of rod?

Comment: Can you add the link to the question that was already answered?

Comment: Maybe: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98904/rod-falling-on-frictionless-surface?rq=1

Comment: @ParthVader They had the lower point stationary. I will edit that line. There was a same question with no answer

Comment: This?: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102120/equation-of-motion-for-a-falling-rod-with-one-end-touching-a-frictionless-surfa?rq=1

Comment: So wait, this is just a rod tipping over right? Rotating a quarter of a circle?

Comment: @DavePhD Yes. ­

Comment: @ParthVader Yeah but bottom point would be sliding and the centre of mass will fall straight down

Comment: How will the bottom point slide? Slide where?

Comment: @ParthVader It must slide on the ground opposite to direction you gave the little push. The centre of mass must not move horizontally

Comment: I can't figure it how to calculate it in that situation. Without the sliding, you can just use energy conservation to get $\omega$.

Comment: @ParthVader That's why I posted it. This has been bothering me very much.

Comment: I still don't understand how exactly it will slide, that is why I'm having difficulty in formulating anything.

Comment: @ParthVader See first link by David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did and I think is simple and right :

Assume $v$ linear speed of centre of mass downwards and $\omega$ angular speed around it. Use the fact the bottom point has no vertical speed to find relation between $v$ and $\omega$. And I am done.

Answer (score 2):

The translational kinetic energy is simply $\frac{1}{2} m v^2$ where $v$ is the velocity of the center of mass.

Rotational kinetic energy is $E_r = \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2$. To solve the problem, we must write the velocity of the rod as function of $\omega$ (or vice versa).

[image]

Consider the above image. (Note that my convention for $\theta$ is different from yours - my apologies). The red vector is the linear velocity of the rod, $v$. The orange vector is the component of this velocity which is perpendicular to the rod, $v \cos(\theta)$. From the bottom point of the rod, the linear velocity a distance $l/2$ away is $v \cos(\theta)$, so the angular velocity $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \omega = \frac{2v \cos(\theta)}{l}$.

Using this result, we can find the rotational kinetic energy to be $E_r = \frac{1}{2} \frac{m l^2}{12} \left(\frac{2v \cos(\theta)}{l}\right)^2$. This expression (along with the other energy terms) can be used to solve a differential equation to obtain $\theta$ or $v$ as a function of time. As you found in your question, $N = mg - ma = mg - m \frac{dv}{dt}$, so you can use this relation to find the normal force as a function of time.

Comment: I really want to see how we would do it from instantaneous centre of rotation. Please just tell me what to do. No need to write long explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by "from instantaneous centre of rotation"? Do you mean the position of the center of rotation?

Comment: I mean the point from where only rotational motion occurs. Its coordinates can be found by intersection of normals from path of centre of mass and bottommost point.

Comment: I might just be having a bad day, but I still don't get it. The motion of the rod is completely rotation with reference to the bottommost point, but that point is accelerating, so it's not a inertial frame of reference. Is that what you mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_centre_of_rotation

Comment: Can we just take its speed to centre of mass to correspond to translational kinetic energy and then find rotational kinetic energy from it? It is a non inertial frame though.

Comment: Both the translational and angular velocities need to be measured from the center of mass (as stated here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Rotating_bodies). Using the center of rotation may also work, though, with a modified approach.

Comment: Can you please tell about the approach?

Comment: The bottom most point is non inertial frame of reference but it works because work done by pseudo force is here zero?