# A stick is positioned vertically and allowed to fall. What is its speed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

Consider the following situation:
"A thin stick of mass m and length l is positioned vertically, with its
tip on a frictionless table. It is released and allowed to fall."

This question may also be asked: "What is the speed of the center of mass of the stick just before it hits the table?"

You can say initial potential energy is equal to final kinetic energy conservation of energy:

[image: first]

Then you relate translational and rotational velocity and solve for translational velocity. The final answer for impact velocity comes out to this:

[image: this]

All the solutions I can find, including my own, agree with this, however they do not all agree with on that relation between translational and rotational velocity. Most solutions use the first one below, but I believe it should be the second (theta is the angle off the horizontal):

[image: this]

[image: that]

This doesn't make a difference for the impact velocity since the two expressions become equal as [image: this], but it's still a pretty nontrivial mistake. I thought [image: thing] only described circular motion of the center of mass. There is a similar problem in which one end of a stick is constrained to a hinge on a wall such that one of its ends can only slide up and down. In this problem the center of mass does undergo circular motion and I believe that relation would be accurate, but not in the problem of just falling straight down. Am I misunderstanding something?

Edit:
I came up with my expression because the stick must fall straight down -- there is no initial horizontal velocity and there are no horizontal forces.

[image: thing]

Comment: Why do you think your result for $v_{cm}$ is correct?

Comment: Because y = .5 l sin(theta) -> v_y = .5 d(theta)/dt cos(theta)

Comment: motion will be only downward so v_cm = v_y

Comment: Your equation gives the relation between $\omega$ and the *vertical component* of $v_{cm}$. As you point out, there is no x-component when the CM reaches the ground. The 2 expressions are the same when the rod hits the ground $(\theta=0)$, but your equation does not give the correct relation before then $(\theta \gt 0)$.

Comment: But isn't the vertical component of v_cm is the only component of v_cm?
There are no horizontal forces.

Comment: Yes, the CM only moves vertically *relative to the stationary ground.*  But the equation you are asking about is measuring $v_{cm}$ *relative to the moving stick.*

Comment: The velocity relative to the stationary ground is what counts though since that is the inertial frame. You can treat kinetic energy as translation of center of mass (in inertial frame) + rotation about center of mass

Comment: I am beginning to see what you mean. Have you taken into account that the pivot point at the end of the stick (from which $\frac12 l$ is measured) is also moving?

Comment: I think the pivot point moving is taken into account. I think you just need an accurate expression for your center of mass velocity and your rotation about the center of mass.
On the other hand, if it were _not_ moving, the center of mass would be undergoing a circular motion and the other formula would in fact be accurate

Comment: This problem is also discussed at length in [The Equation of motion for a falling rod (with one end touching a frictionless surface)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102120) and [Rod sliding on a frictionless surface](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107301).

Comment: Yes, I think you may be correct that the factor of $\cos\theta$ does take into account that he pivot is moving.

Comment: Ah, that is very thorough. Thank you, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

$v_{CM} = \frac{l}{2} \omega$ gives the speed of the stick's center of mass relative to the point of contact between the stick and ground, which is not stationary with respect to the surface in this instance (since we are given a *frictionless* surface). In this case, since friction is not present, there are no horizontal forces on the stick, meaning its center of mass will move only in a vertical line. And if you consider the triangle formed by that vertical line, the lower half of the stick, and the surface, it can be seen that the ratio of the height of the center of mass $h$ to the lower half of the stick $\frac{l}{2}$ is equal to $\cos{\theta}$, that is $\frac{h}{\frac{l}{2}}=\cos{\theta}$. Differentiation wrt time gives, $\frac{\dot{h}}{\frac{l}{2}}=\cos{\theta} \, \dot{\theta}$, since $l$ is constant, and once rearranged, that is $v_{CM}=\frac{l}{2}\omega \cos{\theta}$.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your formula is correct, but, as @sammy gerbil notes, the second formula is good enough for the purpose of solving the problem, as it is correct at the moment when the stick hits the ground. His remark about the speed of your formula being negative is correct, but that does not make your formula incorrect: both the speed and the angular velocity are negative (both $y_{cm}$ and $\theta$ decrease).